# Last data of datalist is empty

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am using this code for changing a label value in `datalist` but when I run the project all of them is correct but the last data is empty.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) {

  javidDataContextdc=new javidDataContext();
  foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
  {

    string itemID = DataList1.DataKeys[0].ToString();

    Label lbl1 = (Label)li.FindControl("Label1");

    Label lblt = (Label)li.FindControl("lblt");
    lblt.Text = (from p in dc.tbl_writer_translators where p.wid == int.Parse(lbl1.Text) select p.fullname).First();

  }

}
```

Comment: To debug this, what have you tried so far? Have you tried stepping through the loop in the debugger (or even using print statements) to verify that your Linq query is actually finding a non-blank value for the last iteration?

Comment: yes i have two record for test i used a counter for this but it count 1 record .